# Windows application or service to communicate with another service on remote desktop

Tags: c#, windows-services, service

I need to write an application in C# that has to communicate with a service on a remote desktop. I would like to know if it will be better to write an application that sends information to a local service which in turn communicates with the remote service or would it be better for the application itself to communicate with the remote service directly?

Are there any advantages of using 1 method over the other?

EDIT:
The data is in the form of XML that is being passed to the service and there will be multiple instances of the objects in the application that will be sending and receiving information to and from the service.

Example:
Lets say that the application needs to retrieve a certain user's information from a DB. This DB is installed on another remote computer. There is a service on the remote computer that receives requests for information from the DB which it then retrieves, converts it to XML, and then forward this XML to the requesting application.

Comment: Only answer: It depends. Provide context and we can advice, but without context this is "what is better - spaghetti or steak".

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If this is specifically about communicating between your machine and a remote machine, whilst using Remote Desktop/Terminal Services, that you might be looking for [Remote Desktop Services Virtual Channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).